# Adding fractions from subsets of variables

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

```
Clear[exp]
exp[dist_] := Module[{nonemptysubsets, fractions, signs},
  nonemptysubsets = Complement[Subsets[dist], {{}}];
  fractions = 1/Map[Total, nonemptysubsets];
  signs = Map[(-1)^(Length[#] + 1) &, nonemptysubsets];
  Dot[signs, fractions]
  ]
exp[{x,y}]
```

gives the output

```
1/x + 1/y - 1/(x + y)
```

as expected.
Yet

```
exp[{1,1}]
```

gives the output

```
1/2
```

rather than

```
3/2
```

as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may or may not be a bug depending on how you look at it. Perhaps it's just undocumented behaviour. `Subsets[{1,1}]` returns `{{},{1},{1},{1,1}}` but `Complement[Subsets[{1, 1}], {{}}]` returns `{1},{1,1}` because `Complement` will turn the list into a set and a duplicate `{1}` disappears.

Instead of using `Complement` just remove cases of `{}` using `DeleteCases[Subsets[dist], {}]`

Comment: Brilliant ! Thank you very much. You are very polite - you avoided pointing out that I am indeed dumb !

Comment: Well you aren't dumb because your code is at least well formatted! You should consider changing the title of the question though. Choose something appropriate like *Adding fractions from subsets of variables* as it will be easier for others to search for should they need to.

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be caused by the fact that `Subsets` does not treat its first argument as set. In the concrete case, `Subsets[{1, 1}]` returns

> {{}, {1}, {1}, {1, 1}}

which actually shocked me because the subsets should be just

> {{}, {1}}

You can apply `Union` to resolve this. You should also get rid of the empty set with `Rest`:

```
Rest[Subsets[Union[dist]]]
```

> {{1}}

But I am not sure whether that is what you wanted, because `exp[{1, 1}]` would return just `1`...

Comment: Thank you very much ! It seems, per flinty's answer, that Complement "setifies" the list.

Comment: Partially, it "setifies". But it cannot take care of `{1,1}` which I would either not consider a mathematical subset of the "set" $\{1,1\}$ or I had to identify $\{1,1\}$ with $\{ 1 \}$ - and then the list of subsets (with duplicates removed) would be again $\{1\}$... But what is "right" here depends of course on your application. =)

Comment: Yes, it's more like Sub-multisets and I reckon it's like that because it's more useful for programming _(think things like all possible groupings ignoring order)_ than the strict mathematical definition which you can get with `Subsets[DeleteDuplicates[{1, 1}]]`